# T-SQL Cursor in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I am using a stored procedure and I want to use cursor for inserting new data (if data exist I want to update)

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[conn]
    @ResellerID int,
    @GWResellerID int,
    @UserName varchar(50),
    @Password varchar(50),
    @URL varchar(100),
    @ServiceType int,
    @ServiceDesc varchar(50),
    @FeedFrom bit,
    @PublicKey varchar(max)
AS
    declare gateway cursor for
         select * 
         from reseller_profiles 
         where main_reseller_ID = @ResellerID

    OPEN gateway

    FETCH NEXT FROM gateway INTO @ResellerID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO [dbo].tblGatewayConnection([ResellerID],[GWResellerID], [UserName], [Password], [URL], [ServiceType], [ServiceDesc],[feedFromMain], publicKey)
       VALUES (@ResellerID, @GWResellerID, @UserName, @Password, @URL, @ServiceType, @ServiceDesc, @FeedFrom, @PublicKey)

       FETCH NEXT FROM gateway INTO @ResellerID
    END

    CLOSE gateway
    DEALLOCATE gateway
```

My table name is `tblGatewayConnection` has these columns:

```
resellerID
gwResellerID
userName
password
url
serviceType
serviceDesc
feedFromMain
publicKey
```

While I insert data using the stored procedure, I get an exception

> Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns.

What did I miss ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: First: ***why*** do you insist on doing this with a cursor?? **AVOID** RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) processing whenever you can!!

Comment: Don't use `select * from …` in production code. Likely you're getting multiple columns from the query; but you only supply a single variable in the `into` clause,

Comment: You're also using `@ResellerID` as part of the cursor's query and for its results: if nothing else this is confusing,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why even bother with a cursor?!?!?!?!? I won't tell you what's wrong with your cursor - because instead of fixing the cursor, you should learn **to avoid it** in the first place!

Seriously - **avoid** RBAR (**row-by-agonizing-row**) processing whenever you can, and here, it's really utterly pointless to use a cursor - just use this nice and clean **set-based** statement:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[conn] @ResellerID   INT,
                             @GWResellerID INT,
                             @UserName     VARCHAR(50),
                             @Password     VARCHAR(50),
                             @URL          VARCHAR(100),
                             @ServiceType  INT,
                             @ServiceDesc  VARCHAR(50),
                             @FeedFrom     BIT,
                             @PublicKey    VARCHAR(max)
AS
    INSERT INTO dbo.tblGatewayConnection
                (ResellerID, GWResellerID, UserName, Password,
                 URL, ServiceType, ServiceDesc, feedFromMain,
                 publicKey)
       SELECT 
          ResellerID, GWResellerID, UserName, Password,
          URL, ServiceType, ServiceDesc, feedFromMain,
          publicKey
       FROM   
          dbo.reseller_profiles
       WHERE  
          main_reseller_ID = @ResellerID
```

and you're done!! No messy cursor, no unnecessary local variables - just a simple `INSERT ... SELECT` and you've achieved what you want!

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure the error message could be any more self explanatory:

> Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns.

You are selecting **all** the columns from `reseller_profiles`

```
declare gateway cursor for
     select * 
     from reseller_profiles 
     where main_reseller_ID = @ResellerID
```

And trying to put them into a single variable:

```
FETCH NEXT FROM gateway INTO @ResellerID
```

The number of columns you select in your cursor must match the number of variables you are inserting to, so you would need something like

```
declare gateway cursor for
     select reseller_id
     from reseller_profiles 
     where main_reseller_ID = @ResellerID
```

**HOWEVER** you should not be using a cursor for this, you can use the same thing using `INSERT .. SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].tblGatewayConnection
(   [ResellerID],[GWResellerID], [UserName], [Password], [URL], 
    [ServiceType], [ServiceDesc],[feedFromMain], publicKey
)
SELECT  Resellerid, @GWResellerID, @UserName, @Password, 
        @URL, @ServiceType, @ServiceDesc, @FeedFrom, @PublicKey
FROM    reseller_profiles 
WHERE   main_reseller_ID = @ResellerID;
```

As has been said, you should avoid cursors at all costs, if you absolutely have to use a cursor, declare the most light weight cursor you can. In your case for example, you were only moving forwards within the cursor, only reading data, not modifying it, and only accessing the cursor locally, therefore you would declare the cursor as follows:

```
DECLARE gateway CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FAST_FORWARD
FOR
    SELECT  ...
    FROM ..
```

Although cursors perform terribly at the best of times they are given an even worse reputation by lazy declarations.

Finally, [You should get out of the habit of using `SELECT *`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)